# suspend to RAM stopped USB speakers

Tags: usb, sound

I use a Teufel C 200 USB System on Natty, which worked fine with Mavarick and Natty so far. A couple minutes ago, I did a suspend to RAM, woke the computer up a little later and the speakers to not play anything anymore.

I tried maxing everything in the "Sound" Menu in System Settings, tried `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol`, everything is at 100% and the USB device is selected.

The system was restarted twice after that, so that should not be the issue.

When I hook the same speakers to my Natty Laptop, I can just select them as the audio device and music plays.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blacklisting the internal intel soundcard removed it from the sound menu, but there was no sound still. I tried starting `alsamixer` again and it had different options now, "speaker" was turned down to zero.

It was the easiest of all possible problems after all …

Is probably has a lot to do with [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40305/usb-audio-on-0-volume-on-startup), this seems to be the solution for the wrong problem.