# USB Audio on 0 volume on startup

Tags: usb, sound

I have a USB Audio system, on every system start, its volume is zero. I cannot set it with the regular sound widget in the notification area but have to use `alsamixer` in the terminal.

Any ideas why it is reduced to zero on every startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I purged the `.pulse` folder in my home directory, the sound is now online on startup.