# USB Bose speakers with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, usb

On a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 my Bose USB weren't working at all.

I read through a large number of posts here and elsewehre on Bose or USB speakers.  I tried many things (modifying a number of different files, etc.).

This worked... sort of:  [USB Audio on 0 volume on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40305/usb-audio-on-0-volume-on-startup)

The AlsaMixer works after I turn up the volume, but the sound crackles a lot.  Also, having to use a term mixer to change sound isn't ideal.

Any other ideas?

Thank you,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

I've Bose companion 5 and it worked like charm with Ubuntu 12.04. Check the sound settings once you connected the USB, you should see Bose listed in the 'output' tab; select it, you are done.